# Not able to use workspaces in ubuntu 20.04. Toogle workspace gnome extention is showing error can anyone help me?

Tags: 20.04, gnome, ubuntu-gnome, gnome-software

[image]

My workspaces are not working, toogle work space gnome extension is also showing error please refer the screen shot attached

Comment: The extension that you mention does not seem to have been updated for a very long time.  What happens when you press the 'super' key - do you see the primary and a secondary workspace along the right side of your screen?

Comment: Start the app "Gnome Tweaks" or the one called "Extensions", and disable this workspace extension. See if it improves things. Probably it will.

Comment: Hi Charles thank you for responding, I am able to see primary and secondary workspaces but not able to customise them.

Comment: @Levente thanks for your response but it did not work for me.

Comment: I want multiple workspace accessible from right hand  corner of screen, tried everything but nothing works please refer the link. i am new to ubuntu. http://www.craiglotter.co.za/2012/02/20/ubuntu-11-10-how-to-change-workspaces-using-the-unity-workspace-switcher-keyboard-shortcut/

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the workspace extension you mention, and the link you mention for workspaces both come from Ubuntu 11, running Unity.

Things have changed - your running gnome, and Ubuntu 20.04

[this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-workspaces.html) will give you information about how workspaces run in today's systems.

If you use extensions to change the workspaces, please look for extensions compatible with gnome 3.36 or higher